# How do I run the openstack chef cookbook?

Tags: chef-infra, openstack

I am trying to deploy openstack on a standalone machine using chef, with the cookbooks included in https://github.com/stackforge/openstack-chef-repo , refered to here: http://docs.opscode.com/openstack_repository.html . Specifically, I'm trying to set up the `os-compute-single-controller` role.

I was able to upload the cookbooks without a hitch.

However, when I tried to run the I stumbled on this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT
-------------
No such file or directory - file not found '/etc/chef/openstack_data_bag_secret'

Cookbook Trace:
---------------
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/openstack-common/libraries/passwords.rb:45:in `secret'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/openstack-common/libraries/passwords.rb:62:in `db_password'
  /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/openstack-ops-database/recipes/openstack-db.rb:27:in `from_file'

Relevant File Content:
----------------------
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/openstack-common/libraries/passwords.rb:

 38:    # That means nova_password will == "nova".
 39:    def secret bag_name, index
 40:      if node["openstack"]["developer_mode"]
 41:        return index
 42:      end
 43:      key_path = node["openstack"]["secret"]["key_path"]
 44:      ::Chef::Log.info "Loading encrypted databag #{bag_name}.#{index} using key at #{key_path}"
 45>>     secret = ::Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret key_path
 46:      ::Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load(bag_name, index, secret)[index]
 47:    end
 48:  
 49:    # Ease-of-use/standardization routine that returns a service password
 50:    # for a named OpenStack service. Note that databases are named
 51:    # after the OpenStack project nickname, like "nova" or "glance"
 52:    def service_password service
 53:      bag = node["openstack"]["secret"]["service_passwords_data_bag"]
 54:      secret bag, service
```

Am I missing something? I don't mind writing a recipe to populate this file, but I'm unsure what should go in it. I was unable to find anything in the documentation for these cookbooks about this file.

This is the configuration I'm specifying for chef client:

```
{"run_list":["recipe[apache2]", "role[os-compute-single-controller]"]}
```

EDIT:

Creating an empty file results in an error: `invalid zero length secret in '/etc/chef/openstack_data_bag_secret'`

[This](https://github.com/openstack-titanium-community/OScommon/blob/9a72501fcf04427b2f90c4a82a40e0c73f9fdd9f/barclamp/hacommon/chef/cookbooks/yum/openstack-common/files/default/openstack_data_bag_secret) seems related, albeit from a different repository. But why is [this recipe](https://github.com/openstack-titanium-community/OScommon/blob/9a72501fcf04427b2f90c4a82a40e0c73f9fdd9f/barclamp/hacommon/chef/cookbooks/yum/openstack-common/recipes/manage_encrypted_db.rb) not in the [stackforge repository](https://github.com/stackforge/openstack-chef-repo)?

Comment: It should not be an empty file. It should be a key with what you encrypted the data in the databag.

Comment: @Ovesh, please give feedback if you had any further problems related to this. I'm willing to improve this Q&A for anyone who might drop by later on.

Comment: @Konzula, I do have more issues, but not directly related to this. To be honest, I was able to resolve the data bag issue before you responded. I just wish there was a more complete walkthrough of the cookbooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your log says the error is actually raised in the cookbook: "stackforge/cookbook-openstack-common", by the class.method [::Chef::EncryptedDataBagItem.load_secret](http://rubydoc.info/gems/chef/0.10.4/Chef/EncryptedDataBagItem) .

[Here's](http://cookingclouds.com/2012/06/23/chef-encrypted-data-bags-example/) how you'll generate the secret file (with content), and place it where it should be.

Keep in mind that your secret file location(path) is being kept in [your cookbook attribute file](https://github.com/stackforge/cookbook-openstack-common/blob/master/attributes/default.rb). Variable:
 `node["openstack"]["secret"]["key_path"]`  So pay attention that this variable is in sync with the actual location of the file.

Comment: Alternately you can set the developer_mode attribute and run from attributes (see the example environment files in the repo) instead of creating the databags for a production setup.